# How to force a div to always be scrollable?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am using `Angular 4` along with `Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6)`. I'm using `ngx-infinte-scroll` so that I can fetch data from the server when the user scrolls to either the top or bottom of the div. The problem is that the user can only scroll if there are enough items. I want to make it so that they can always scroll. How can I make it so that the vertical scroll bar is always showing? The content that needs to be scrollable is in the `item-scroller` class

```
<div class="col-md-9 chat-column">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-block item-body">
      <h4 class="card-title center">Test</h4>
      <hr/>
      <div class="item-scroll"
           infinite-scroll
           [infiniteScrollDistance]="0.99"
           [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="0.075"
           [infiniteScrollThrottle]="10"
           [scrollWindow]="false"
           (scrolled)="onScrolledDown()"
           (scrolledUp)="onScrolledUp()"
      >
        <div *ngFor="let i of is">
          {{i}}
        <div class="answer left">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img [src]="i.imageURL" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="name">{{i.name}}</div>
          <div class="text">
            {{i.text}}
          </div>
          <div class="when">{{i.when}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item-scroll {
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex:none;
}

.item-body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

Things i've tried

1)

```
.item-scroll {
  height: 101%
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex:none;
}

.item-body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

2)

```
.item-scroll {
  height: 101%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex:none;
}

.item-body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

3)

```
.item-scroll {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0 0 0 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex:none;
}

.item-body {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the **!important** in the overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your styles in correct order and use `100vh` instead of percentage values. Here is an example:

```
.item-body {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
}

.item-scroll {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In my project I use [angular2-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/rintoj/angular2-virtual-scroll) and have similar construct of my code.